# Multi-criteria search in Symfony 3.4

Tags: doctrine, symfony-3.4

I'm finally working on a project in Symfony 3 and it's really very interesting. I encounter new problems and new questions that I want to share with you.

I work on a search form for publications according to several criteria. (I have 3 fields input text: date, category and keyword).

So I handle publication consisting of a date of creation, linked to a category by oneToMany relation [Publication is the entity owning, each publication to a single category] and having several several Tag [there is a ManyToMany relationship with the Tag entity. The search form allows to search by dateCreation, Category and Tag. On the right of the publication list I have a form to perform the search.

[image]

```
 <div>
                <span class="titlerecherche">recherche</span>
                <div class="formrecherch">
                    <form action="{{ url('search_english_pub') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="input" name="date" placeholder="Date *" required></div>
                             </div>

                        <div class="form_row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><input type="text" name="categorie" class="input" placeholder="Catégorie *" required></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><input type="text" name="tag" class="input" placeholder="Tag *" required></div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btnForm">Envoyer <i class="icon-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In my entity I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUMjg.png)

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: I managed to display the publications by date but I could not display them by category that has an ontomany relationship with publication (priority entity) or by tag that has manytomany relationship with publication known that i want to display them by   knowing that I want to display them by these three "date, category and tag  " criteria

Comment: this the method that i created to display by date   : public function searchAction()
    {   $request= $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
        $date = $request->request->get('date');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $listEnglishs = $em->getRepository('MDWEBInEnglishBundle:InEnglish')->findBy(array(
            "date" => new \DateTime($date) )
       );

        
        return $this->render('MDWEBFrontBundle:InEnglish:list.html.twig',array('listEnglishs'=>$listEnglishs));
    }

Comment: Please copy your `class` code from your editor, so that it contains line breaks.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots with text only. And if you use images, check if they work.

Answer (score 0):

If only you could edit question and provide more details so i can help more
in the mean time try this:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $date = $request->request->get('date');
        $category = $request->request->get('category');
        $keyword = $request->request->get('keyword');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $listEnglishs = $em->getRepository('MDWEBInEnglishBundle:InEnglish')
            ->findBy(array("date" => new \DateTime($date), "category" => $category, "keyword" => $keyword));
        return $this->render('MDWEBFrontBundle:InEnglish:list.html.twig',
            array('listEnglishs' => $listEnglishs));
    }
```

also add this at the top

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Comment: in my entity i have class Publication{ /** * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) / private $date; /* * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MDWEB\ActualiteBundle\Entity\Categorie") * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie_id", referencedColumnName="id") / private $Categorie; /* * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MDWEB\ActualiteBundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"}) * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tag_english") */ private $tags; }